# sed-ish oneliner to perform arithmetic within substitution

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a string of form `FOO_123_BAR.bazquux`, where `FOO` and `BAR` are fixed strings, `123` is a number and `bazquux` is freeform text.

I need to perform a text transformation on this string: extract `123` and `bazquux`, increment the number and then arrange them in a different string.
For example, `FOO_123_BAR.bazquux` ⇒ `FOO=124 BAR=bazquux`.
(Actual transformation is more complex.)

Naturally, I can do this in a sequence of sed and expr calls, but it's ugly:

```sh
shopt -s lastpipe

in=FOO_123_BAR.bazquux
echo "$in" | sed -r 's|^FOO_([0-9]+)_BAR\.(.+)$|\1 \2|' | read number text
out="FOO=$((number + 1)) BAR=$text"
```

Is there a more powerful text processing tool that can do the job in a single invocation? If yes, then how?

---

Edit: I apologize for not making this clearer, but the exact structure of the input and output is an example. Thus, I prefer general solutions that work with any delimiters or absence thereof, rather than solutions that depend on e. g. presence of underscores.

Comment: Do you want a  suggestion using bash regex or string manipulations? if not retaining the bash tag doesn't make sense

Comment: @Inian I'm certainly open to oneliners in pure bash :)

Comment: wtrt your edit that `I prefer general solutions that work with any delimiters or absence thereof` - what if you replace `FOO` and `BAR` with different "fixed strings" like `F.O` and `B/R'`? If you would expect the solution you accepted to keep working then you'd be disappointed. You can't get a general solution from 1 input example and an informal description like "fixed strings" and the solution you picked doesn't use "fixed strings" at all, it uses a regular expression because that's good enough to produce the expected output from the one sample input you provided.

Comment: @EdMorton a regular expression can be trivially adapted to any `FOO` and `BAR`, or even to completely different inputs. The solution that uses awk to break on `_` and `.` as delimiters — can't. I hope this explains my logic in choosing the accepted answer.

Comment: It's messy and cumbersome at best to try to make a regexp operate as if it were using strings (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/29613304/1745001) and you don't need either approach, you can just use literal strings, it's just not clear from your question which is the best approach for your problem. It sounds from your comment like a literal strings approach may have been the right approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `GNU sed`, you can execute the entire replacement string as an external command using the `e` flag.

```
$ s='FOO_123_BAR.bazquux'
$ echo "$s" | sed -E 's/^FOO_([0-9]+)_BAR\.(.+)$/echo FOO=$((\1 + 1)) BAR=\2/e'
FOO=124 BAR=bazquux
```

To avoid conflict with shell metacharacters, you need to quote the unknown portions:

```
$ s='FOO_123_BAR.$x(1)'
$ echo "$s" | sed -E 's/^FOO_([0-9]+)_BAR\.(.+)$/echo FOO=$((\1 + 1)) BAR=\2/e'
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

$ echo "$s" | sed -E 's/^FOO_([0-9]+)_BAR\.(.+)$/echo FOO=$((\1 + 1)) BAR=\x27\2\x27/e'
FOO=124 BAR=$x(1)
```

Comment: I did not know about the `e` flag to the `s///` sed command. Thanks, this (alongside with perl) is the cleanest solution (although a GNUism, but I don't care about that here).

Comment: @intelfx cool, see [my tutorial for e flag](https://github.com/learnbyexample/learn_gnused/blob/master/gnu_sed.md#executing-external-commands) for more examples and details... although, I'd say that Ed Morton's take by processing the input as fields is the cleanest for this particular format..

Comment: I should've clarified this earlier — I do not like solutions that depend on a particular format, because their general utility is lower.

Comment: @intelfx **every** text processing solution depends on a particular format, you just have to tell us what the format is and provide sample input/output that we can use to verify our potential solution works for **that** format and not some other similar but invalid format.

Answer (score 5):

Using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box and assuming none of your substrings contain `_` or `.`:

```
$ s='FOO_123_BAR.bazquux'
$ echo "$s" | awk -F'[_.]' '{print $1"="$2+1,$3"="$4}'
FOO=124 BAR=bazquux
```

Answer (score 4):

You may do it with `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's|^FOO_([0-9]+)_BAR\.(.+)$|"FOO=" . ($1 + 1) . " BAR=" . $2|e' <<< "$in"
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/AruIuV)

The `($1 + 1)` will increment the number captured in Group 2.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

***1st solution:*** Adding solution with `match` function `awk`.

```
echo "FOO_123_BAR.bazquux" | 
awk '
match($0,/FOO_[0-9]+_BAR/){
  split(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),array,"_")
  print array[1]"="array[2]+1,array[3] "=" substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)
}'
```

---

---

***2nd solution:***

```
echo "FOO_123_BAR.bazquux" | 
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS="_"
}
{
  $2+=1
  sub(/_/,"=")
  sub(/_/," ")
  sub(/\./,"=")
}
1'
```

Answer (score 2):

A pure `bash` one-liner would be

```
[[ $s =~ FOO_([0-9]+)_BAR\.(.*) ]] && echo "FOO=$((BASH_REMATCH[1] + 1)) BAR=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
```

assuming the variable `s` is set to the string that is being parsed before calling that line (`s=FOO_123_BAR.bazquux`).

Answer (score 1):

Using var substitution:

```
in=FOO_123_BAR.bazquux
raw=(${in//_/ })
$ echo "$raw=$[raw[1]+1] ${raw[2]//./=}"
FOO=124 BAR=bazquux
```